# Why does asp.net copy DLLs to their own directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

As part of the dynamic compilation stage, asp.net copies the dependent DLLs for my web application to the temporary internet files directory. All of the files end up in their own directory with a randomly generated name.

- What is the purpose of this?
- Why not directly copy the /bin directory structure to the new location, without separating the files into their own directories?